# Varchar to Int error on Pivot Table Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have list of account number and team IDs in a table. The datatypes for each column are Account number = varchar(16) and the Team ID is varchar(9). I'm trying to pivot so that the data is displayed by account number across the two teams.

My query is....

```
    SELECT  A,
            B

    FROM

(SELECT CAST(AccountID AS INT) AS AccountID,
        CAST(Team AS INT) AS Team

FROM dbo.Client_Download

) AS SourceTable

Pivot

(MAX(AccountID)
For Team in ([A],[B])) As CvgPivot
```

I've tried to keep this as simple as possible but continually keep getting the following error

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'URXQ14GBTHQJ' to data type int.
```

I've tried placing the CAST command on all variations on the query and I still come back to the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sounds like you either have an AccountID or Team called `'URXQ14GBTHQJ'` so why do you think you can cast that to an int? Put the `PIVOT` completely aside, don't you get the same error from `SELECT CAST(AccountID AS INT) AS AccountID, CAST(Team AS INT) AS Team FROM dbo.Client_Download;`?

Comment: Hi Aaron, I don't want to cast them into Int its the error message that SQL is producing. If you can tell me how to avoid that it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have doesn't actually make sense. In the inner select, you `CAST` the value of `Team` to an `int`, however, in the `PIVOT` you want the `MAX` value of `AccountID` where the value of `Team` is `'A'` or `'B'`; neither `'A'` or `'B'` are an `int`...

Comment: *"If you can tell me how to avoid that it would be greatly appreciated."* The obvious answer would be to not explicitly cast the column to an `int` in your `SELECT`... Why is it there is you don't want to convert the value? What do you think `CAST` does?

Comment: `I don't want to cast them into Int` - well, then why does your query say, for example, `CAST(Team AS INT) AS Team`? SQL Server didn't produce that code, you did.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are converting values to ints.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT A, B
FROM (SELECT AccountID, Team
      FROM dbo.Client_Download
     ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (MAX(AccountID)
      For Team in ([A],[B])) As CvgPivot
```